# Determine the closure, interior and boundary of the set

Tags: general-topology

[image]

What does it mean when it asks for the interior of the set?

Also to check, I think this set is open with the boundary at x=0 and an open disk with a radius 1. Am I correct?

Comment: (in standard topology) the interior of a set is the set of points surrounded by an open ball such that this ball is contained your set. your idea about the set is right.

Answer (score 2):

You have almost identified the boundary. It's the point at the origin, together with the *circle* of radius $1$ centred at the origin, not the disc.

The interior of a set is the entire set, minus the boundary, if that applies (it doesn't in this case). More technically, the interior of a set $A$ is the largest open set contained in $A$.

The closure of a set is the entire set, *plus* the boundary. More technically, the closure of a set $A$ is the smallest closed set that contains $A$.

Comment: As an addendum, one useful way to define the interior is as the union of all open subsets of $A$, and the closure is the intersection of all closed supersets of $A$, while the boundary is the closure minus the interior.